# What is this weed and how do I get rid of it?

Tags: weed-control, identification

I'm located in northern Utah, USA.

There is a weed which is proving difficult to control, which I haven't been able to identify.

[image: Tall Ground Runner Weed]

It is usually fairly easy to pull, but you only get a small bit of root because these things spread via an underground runner. Usually there will be dozens all along one run, yet removing them all is almost impossible because of surrounding plants that I want to keep.

The one pictured is in the seeding stage, I usually try not to let them get this far.

What is it, and is there some type of control that is especially effective on it?

**Edit:**

I am adding two additional photos as well as links to larger resolution versions.

[image: Base of weed.]

[(Click for high-res of base)](http://www.redtailed.com/se/weed_base.jpg)

[image: Top of weed.]

[(Click for high-res of top)](http://www.redtailed.com/se/weed_top.jpg)

Comment: It doesn't really look like it from the picture, but I suppose it might be a knapweed of some sort (*Centaurea* sp.). Could you post close-up pictures of the flowers (it would help if you could get a shot of the phyllaries -- the little scale-like leaves at the base of the flowering head), as well as leaves on the stem, and a picture at the base of the plant to see if there is a rosette of leaves there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like a type of fleabane.  I'd say hairy fleabane, yet it is an annual and you mention it spreading by rhizomes.  I suggest you check with Utah Pests http://utahpests.usu.edu/uppdl/.  For only $7, they can ID it for you and tell you how to control it.  Deal!

Comment: Thank you for posting your "expert" answer & please pass on my thanks to [Stephanie Porter](https://twitter.com/skporter) for asking you to look into this question. Your expertise & time is greatly appreciated by myself...

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to stick with my initial thought (as soon as I saw the photo):

- [Common Yarrow](http://extension.usu.edu/weedguides/files/uploads/Asteraceae.pdf#page=1) (Direct link to PDF) from [Utah State University Cooperative Extension](http://extension.usu.edu/)

Though without seeing all of the weed (at ground level) I'm not 100% on the above. <del>Another possibility:</del>

<del>* [Hoary Cress](http://extension.usu.edu/weedguides/files/uploads/brassicaceae.pdf#page=5) (Direct link to PDF) from [Utah State University Cooperative Extension](http://extension.usu.edu/)</del>

Both the above PDF's contain **Control** information.

Listed below is further weed related information, resources from [Utah State University Cooperative Extension](http://extension.usu.edu/):

- [Common Weeds of the Yard and Garden](http://extension.usu.edu/weedguides/htm/common-weeds-of-the-yard-and-garden)
- [Weed Guides](https://extension.usu.edu/weedguides/htm/) (contains 2 excellent **free** PDF downloadable "Weed Guides")

  - Direct link to PDF - [Noxious Weeds Field Guide For Utah](http://www.utahweed.org/PDF/FieldGuide_Ed4.pdf)
  - Direct link to PDF - [Common Weeds Of The Yard And Garden A Guidebook](http://extension.usu.edu/files/publications/publication/Horticulture_Weeds_2011-01pr.pdf)
- [The Weed Web](http://extension.usu.edu/weedweb/)
- [Steps for successful weed control](http://extension.usu.edu/weedweb/ww/steps.htm)

The 288 page, **free** PDF "Weed Management Handbook" from [Montana](http://www.msuextension.org/), [Utah](http://extension.usu.edu/) & [Wyoming](http://www.uwyo.edu/ces/) Cooperative Extension Services is available from:

- [Tooele County Weed Control](http://www.co.tooele.ut.us/weeds.htm)

  - Direct link to PDF - [Weed Management Handbook](http://www.co.tooele.ut.us/PDF/Weeds/weed%20management%20handbook.pdf)

---

Missouri University Extension Office recommended I try this service:

- [Ask an Expert](http://extension.missouri.edu/main/aae.aspx)

So I did, here is the result:

- [Ask an Expert - Question](http://www.extension.org/ask/6d4b9df28a117d3582c3d8fe1bdd72a7)

**Your Question**

> Could you please identify this plant (additional images viewable via URL): [What is this weed and how do I get rid of it?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/1825/394)
>
> My location is... but the plant is located in Northern Utah.

**Responses**

> I am wondering if it could be a knapweed; possibly diffuse knapweed (Centaurea diffusa). See http://forestry.usu.edu/files/uploads/NR_FF/NRFF012.pdf. However, I am a tree expert and non-woody weeds are a little beyond my expertise. Knapweeds are common out here in Utah.

Comment: @JYelton, thanks! I've removed my "Hoary Cress" *guess* (it's most definitely not that). "Common Yarrow" is looking less unlikely now, seeing as the flowers look like they will have a "yellow" centre, surrounded by "white" petals: http://www.redtailed.com/se/weed_top.jpg

Comment: @JYelton, are the stems &/or leaves hairy? From the photos I would say they aren't, but could you please confirm. Does the plant have any kind of smell (from the flower itself, or maybe if you crush a leaf)? If you snap a stem does a white "milky" substance come out?

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with the flora of that area, but based on the flowers, maybe an Erigeron (fleabane)?

Comment: @SteveK Could well be: [Daisy Fleabane](http://www.illinoiswildflowers.info/prairie/plantx/ds_fleabanex.htm) -- with its smoother stems & leaves...

Comment: Erigeron looks good - an open flower would sure help.  One thing that bothers me about both Erigeron and S. Bicolor is the O.P.'s description of the root habit - it doesn't sound like either Solidago or Erigeron, does it?

Comment: @EdStaub *"It is usually fairly easy to pull, but you only get a small bit of root because these things spread via an underground runner."* I agree the description of the root system doesn't fit in with "Daisy Fleabane" (or "Silver-Rod"), it is one of the reasons why I initially went with "Common Yarrow" (but I don't believe that is now correct, having seen further photos)...

Comment: The leaves are not hairy. I am not aware of any particular smell from having pulled and collected these plants. I'll pay closer attention to the "sap" and report on it. I've been quite unable to find a description of this in my plant and weed guides. I definitely don't think it is a fleabane.

Comment: @JYelton Please refer to ["Michelle Wiesbrook" expert answer](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1825/what-is-this-weed-and-how-do-i-get-rid-of-it/1951#1951)

Comment: Knapweed doesn't look like a good fit - the bracts are wrong, and there's too much yellow on our mystery plant.  I don't know knapweed personally though.  A picture of an open flower would sure help.

Comment: @EdStaub I agree. I believe ["Michelle Wiesbrook" expert answer](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1825/what-is-this-weed-and-how-do-i-get-rid-of-it/1951#1951) & ["SteveK" above comment](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1825/what-is-this-weed-and-how-do-i-get-rid-of-it/1827#comment-2611) are most likely correct...

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that it's Silver-Rod (Solidago Bicolor) - even though I don't think it's supposed to grow that far west.  We have a lot around here in New Hampshire.

It's definitely not yarrow - the foliage is all wrong.  The leaves look wrong for hoary cress, too - too small and narrow - though I'm less confident on that.

It should go to seed soon - maybe that will help identify it.

**Update Sept 5 '11**

The new picture of the top shows white petals and yellow stamens, consistent with s. bicolor.   Seeing an open flower would be helpful - the pictures are either buds or flowers gone by.

[Google images for solidago bicolor](http://www.google.com/search?hl=&q=solidago%20bicolor&sourceid=navclient-ff&rlz=1B3GGGL_enUS217US218&ie=UTF-8&biw=1260&bih=817&tbm=ischhttp://www.google.com/search?hl=&q=solidago%20bicolor&sourceid=navclient-ff&rlz=1B3GGGL_enUS217US218&ie=UTF-8&biw=1260&bih=817&tbm=isch), and also see [this guide](http://www.nttlphoto.com/botany/asters-goldenrods/Goldenrods/Solidago/Bicolor/s_bicolor.htm).  Plants get around, and guides get out of date - it wouldn't be at all surprising if it hitchhiked into the state one way or another.  You might want to have a chat with your [county agricultural extension office](https://extension.usu.edu/htm/counties), but they vary a lot from state to state.

Comment: It's definitely not hoary cress -- wrong family. It's in the Asteraceae.

Comment: It has both disk and ray flowers, so it's not *Solidago*.

Comment: @Steve, I'm no botanist, but the guide I referenced above mentioned that for Bicolor, `Both ray and disc florets are WHITE.`  Doesn't that imply that it has both?

Comment: Doh. Yes. And I *am* a botanist, or at least I was one 10 years ago. Can I use the "I was drinking and skyping while stackexchangeing" excuse?